Issue with Knife Project Tool Cutting Unintended Faces in Blender
Question:
I'm experiencing difficulties using the Knife Project tool in Blender. Here's my setup and the problem I'm facing:
I have two objects lying on the XY plane but at different distances on the Z-axis.
The cutting tool object consists of a few rectangular shapes that are not connected to each other. (These two objects were just 2D objects first, I turned the object to be cut into 3D to see if that was the issue, but no)
I select the object to be cut first and enter Edit Mode, then Shift + select the cutting tool and apply the Knife Project from the top orthographic view.
Issue:
When I use the Knife Project tool, it cuts through the object as intended, but it also cuts along the edges of the object, splitting it in half, which I don't want. I just want to create holes in the object without cutting it along its edges. Please see the image below:

Steps I've Tried:
Viewport Perspective: Made sure to be in the top orthographic view (Numpad 7) before applying the Knife Project.
Face Select Mode: Selected only the faces I wanted to cut in Face Select Mode.
Alternative Methods Tried:
Boolean Modifier (Difference Mode): Used a Boolean Modifier to cut holes, but it also splits the object in half. Tried merging vertices and filling faces afterward but still faced difficulties.
Question:
How can I use the Knife Project tool (or any other method) to create holes in an object without cutting it along its edges? What steps should I follow to achieve clean cuts without unintended splits? Are there any specific settings or techniques I’m missing?
Thank you for your help!
UPDATE
After I precut the face in 2 and apply the knife project to open holes on the surface I get the result on the left. As it seen there are two sperate faces (two triangular faces). Can I combine these two faces (and get rid of the diagonal line) to make one rectangular face while keeping the holes there? What I want to achieve is the result on the right one (It looks like the left one does not have diagonal line because it isn't in the edit mode. So don't be confused, I couldn't achieve what I wanted)


This question is similar to: How can eliminate edges connecting surfaces? and this one: Box Cutter showing up edge lines. The simple answer is: you cannot have holes within a mesh without at least 2 connections to surrounding edges. And if you just let a knife project or Boolean operation "choose" automatically where to put them, they might not be the prettiest solution.

Here is an example how to make it "prettier": if you pre-cut the cube diagonally so that the edge would run through all holes and to the outer boundaries, then the Knife Project tool will use the exisiting edges to connedt the holes with the surroundings instead of creating new ones wherever it wants. Here is a before and after (the projection cut was of course top down): pre-defined cuts

@GordonBrinkmann having predefined cuts beforehand sounds like a good idea. Is there a way to connect those faces without filling the holes afterwards? I have tried few options like: dissolve faces etc. but didn't work. Thanks

I do not understand what you mean with "connect those faces"? And "filling the holes"? After using knife project, the holes are filled (because the knife just makes cuts, it does not delete any faces) but the faces inside the new cut holes are selected, so you could simply hit X > Delete > Faces to have holes in the mesh.

Have you even looked at the other explanations? Please read the other answers I've  linked at the beginning. You cannot have holes within a single face, a hole always needs at least two connecting edges to the surrounding geometry, which means a hole must always be formed between two or more faces. I only showed you a possible workaround to make it look less ugly or more predictable. But the main answer remains, you cannot get rid of all edges.
